# join just last record in second table, but include records don't have match in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I know there are a lot similar questions. Actually I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table) and it works, but I can't figure out how to include records, which don't have match in second table.

I use sample Northwind db on MS SQL Server.

Using this Query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderDate) maxDate
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY CustomerID
    ) b ON Orders.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND
            Orders.OrderDate = b.maxDate
ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate
```

I get correct result, but missing records, which don't match.

If I use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderDate) maxDate
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY CustomerID
    ) b ON Orders.CustomerID = b.CustomerID AND
            Orders.OrderDate = b.maxDate
ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate
```

I get missing records, but in this case I have repeated customer names.

I want: get list of customers with only his last order and if he doesn't have order his name should be present anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get duplicate customer names with the inner join?

Comment: no, don't have, just run using ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID to check.

Comment: it looks I found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764413/join-record-with-most-recent-record-on-second-table?rq=1

Comment: . . I don't understand why the left outer join would result in duplicate customer names.  The `left outer join` is one solution, although window functions are a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got repeated customer names, because you link over orderdate. So if you have two or more orders on the last date for some customer you get all these last orders.
If I assume that the orderid has the same sequence as the orderdate, following statement should return only one line for each customer.

```
select cs.*, o.* from customers cs
left outer join (
  select customerid, max(orderid) as orderid from orders
  group by customerid
) lnk on cs.customerid = lnk.customerid
left outer join orders o on lnk.orderid = o.orderid
order by cs.customerid
```

Comment: You're right about OrderID, I did these changes in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this would be CTE with `ROW_NUMBER()` this query will have better cost because you hit `Orders` table only once instead of twice to get the data and once to get max record.

```
WITH    LastOrder
          AS ( SELECT CustomerID
                   ,OrderID
                   ,OrderDate
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY OrderDate DESC ) AS RowNum
                FROM Orders)
    SELECT c.CustomerID
           ,c.CompanyName
           ,lo.OrderID
           ,lo.OrderDate
        FROM Customers AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LastOrder AS lo
            ON c.Customer_id = lo.CustomerID
               AND lo.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: no, it shows repeated customer names with different orders

Comment: @Alex I had to fix my `PARTITION BY` clause. Needed to remove `OrderID` from it. now it should only show last order.

Answer (score 0):

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764494/240564) to resolve this problem.

See the code:

```
select Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
 from Customers
left outer join  Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
where   Orders.OrderDate is null OR
       Orders.OrderDate = 
       ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
           FROM Orders
          WHERE Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID)       
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID
```

It did exactly what I want.

**UPDATE:** It's better to use OrderID instead OrderTime:

```
select Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CompanyName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate
 from Customers
left outer join  Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
where   Orders.OrderID is null OR
       Orders.OrderID = 
       ( SELECT MAX(OrderID)
           FROM Orders
          WHERE Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID)       
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID
```